# Add a video to a data table in visual studio

Tags: c#, database, video, visual-studio-2012, localdb

Am I able to add a video to a data table in my local db. And if so what would be the data type. I am using a file upload controller to upload the videos and I have 3 fields the title, category & description. Is that the best practice or is there some other/better way of doing it?

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you want to save whole of your file into database?
You can only save the path of uploaded video to your database and fetch from the path when needed.